# Почему код для выполнения внешней программы из консоли работает а при его выполнении из браузера - нет?

Tags: php

У меня есть программа для разброса слов предназначенных для заучивания `a.out` написана она на Си. Порылся в документации нашел функцию `exec()` для выполнения программ написанных не на php. Проблема в том что когда я запускаю код через браузер внешняя программа не запускается на выполнение, а когда запускаю код из консоли все работает.

Вот мой код, который я использую для работы из браузера:

```
<?php
    $path = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if($path[1] == 'link')
        exec('./a.out');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="link">link</a>
        <p>$path[1] = <?= $path[1] ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

А вот код который я запускаю из терминала, так как переменная `$_SERVER` из консоли недоступна - ее я просто убираю вместе с условием.

```
<?php
    exec('./a.out');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="link">link</a>
        <p>$path[1] = <?= $path[1] ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Как мне запустить внешнюю программу?? Я знаю что php язык однопоточный - но и код у меня последовательный без какого либо распараллеливания. Не понимаю почему не работает.

Comment: А в условие if заходит?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да она и без условия не выполняется

Comment: Ты посмтри документацию, там можно посмотреть ответ и резльутат выполнения exec. Может ошибки какие выдаёт

Comment: @АлексейШиманский
/var/www/haruproject.space/index.php:11:string '' (length=0) ---- вывод в браузере через var_dump();
/var/www/haruproject.space/index.php:11:string(0) "" ---- тот же самый вывод только через выполнение из консоли, но тут уже программа работает (еще такой момент у меня функция `main` в `a.out` в случае успешного выполнения программы возвращает 0)

Comment: Поставь временно права 777 на текущий файл и на a.out   и проверь снова

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ноль эмоций ))) поведение не поменялось)))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский все работает но только в формате, <form action="index.php">
            <button>кнопка</button>
        </form>

Comment: @АлексейШиманский есть ли способ запускать какой либо php скрипт без тега `form` - напрямую в кнопке указывать файл исполняемого скрипта??? без  тега `form`

Comment: @ReijiAkkerman а что делает a.out? Я имею ввиду, как вы понимаете, что программа выполнилась?

Comment: Тут 2 возможные причины: пользователь из под которого вы запускаете исполняемый файл (apache запускается под своим пользователем, а в консоли вы запускаете под другим), проблемы с относительным путём (попробуйте указать абсолютный). Вообще команда`exec` содержит в себе ещё аргументы. Вы можете посмотреть код и текст, возвращаемые программой. Может это даст больше ясности.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин нуу программа разбрасывает слова в хаотичном порядке в файлах с этими словами находящиеся в этом же каталоге. Открываю редактор текста и вижу какие там значения (остались прежними или поменялись)

Comment: @ArchDemon к сожалению эти варианты проблему не решили. Встроенный php сервер на котором все собственно без ошибок работает дает какую никакую обратную связь. Можно ли как-нибудь посмотреть какие ответы на этот код выдает apache?

Comment: @ReijiAkkerman а apache у вас локальный? То есть a.out в обоих случаях запускается на одной машине? Код возврата (третий аргумент exec) какой в случае с apache? Отображение всех всех ошибок (в том числе нотисов и варнингов) включено в php для apache?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин Сегодня напишу ответ, на свой же вопрос) насчёт кода возврата посмотрю изначально не заметил что там есть такой аргумент. А так проблема оказалась действительно в правах доступа но вовсе не запускаемого файла, а его результата, как оказалось у меня были права на запуск но не на запись в этой папке, моя программа если прям детально смотреть принцип работы не редактировала существующий файл - она просто считывал данные мои старого файла, сортировал слова и записывала новый файл с таким именем в этой же папке - на что у пользователя этой программы прав не было)Обожаю программирование))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При использовании функции `exec()` для внешних программ особенно тех что были написаны собственноручно - необходимо четко понимать что делает вызываемая программа. В данном случае вызываемая программа `a.out` нацелена на рандомный разброс слов в файлах `NW.txt` - для новых слов, и `TNW.txt` - для соответствующего перевода этих слов.

Для того чтобы понимать что происходит на самом деле введем в терминале команду `whoami` - в моем случае я получаю имя пользователя `reiji` вызвавшего  эту команду, теперь посмотрим от чьего имени вызываются программы запускаемые через `apache`. В файле `index.php` записываем инструкцию `var_dump(exec('whoami'))` - в моем случае результат `www-data`.

Поскольку программа `a.out` не просто редактирует содержимое файлов, а полностью пересоздает файл с тем же именем - то для успешного завершения работы этого цикла нужно:

1. дать разрешение пользователю на работу в данном каталоге `sudo chmod -R 755 (тут ваш файл или файлы)`
2. дать разрешение на запуск внешнего исполняемого файла `sudo chmod 755 (исполняемый файл)`
3. установить разрешение на запись используемых внешних файлов `sudo chmod 752 (перезаписываемый файл)`